# Git log tweaks to ignore file change statistics

Tags: git

Is there any way when running a 'git log' command, that one is able to reliably specifically ignore the following line that is output from a git log command.

```
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Comment: Remove the option `--stat` or `--shortstat` from the command.

Comment: Brilliant, works.